# js error when trying to open Paypal

Tags: paypal

I am using wp e-commerce plugin on my worpress site. Whne someone tries to pay for the objects this is the error they get:

Refused to display 'https://www.paypal.com/it/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=EiY0ZaLRo6fkzLHA…e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081986471f9b93cfa01e00b63629be0164db1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Used to work until yesterday...no changes have been made

Answer (score 0):

JUst follow these steps to set up paypal sandbox to your wp-ecomerce.

I have used half a day setting up PayPal Payments Standard to use a sandbox account on WP e-Commerce. On succeeding i have realized that i have wasted a lot of hours on this.
I hope this blog will save others from using too much time on this simple issue.
lets cut to the chase
open https://developer.paypal.com/, create a new sand box account if you don’t have one already.

loggin into the sandbox account and do the following
- set up buyer account by clicking on ” Create a preconfigured account“, under Account Type select “Buyer (Use to represent your customer’s experience) “. Note the password or put your own password also note the email, then save buy clicking on the “Create Account” button at the bottom.
- set up seller account by clicking on ” Create a preconfigured account“, under Account Type select ” Seller (Use to represent yourself as the merchant) ” . Note the password or put your own password also note the email,  then save buy clicking on the “Create Account” button at the bottom.

after setting up the accounts go to your wordpress installation. Open (yoursite.com)/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpsc-settings&tab=gateway&payment_gateway_id=wpsc_merchant_paypal_standard.
Put a Display Name: of your liking.

next to Username: put the email for the seller account that you setup above.
for Account Type: select sandbox in the dropdown.

If your product does not use shipping, select ‘no‘ next to “Send shipping details: ”
while running the checkout process, at the point where the paypal page opens, fill in buyer account email and password.